# How do I take an input from a search bar and handle a search list at the same time with Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a website that looks like Amazon to teach my self how to make a dropshipping website. I made the front page and I already know how to pass variables between two pages.
I made a testpage. It stores the text that the user places into the search bar into a javascript variable called l. It postes l as text on a div called data. Next it sorts out the input from the search bar and changes the search list underneath it accordingly. This works almost perfectly. Except if I try to use my code the variable l is posted and the search list is changed but a fraction of a second later the search list is placed back into it's original order. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <form action="Test1Verkoopwedstrijd2.html" method="get"> 
  <input type="text" name="serialNumber" id="myInput"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</form>

<div id="data"></div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function processForm(){
        var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
            var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
            l = unescape(temp[1]);
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = l;
        }
    processForm();

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `Test1Verkoopwedstrijd2.html` the name of this HTML file?

Comment: Yes it is Test1Verkoopwedstrijd2.html.

Comment: Once you click on the button with the `onclick` event and the `submit` type, you are essentially telling the browser to make a `GET` request to fetch the `Test1Verkoopwedstrijd2.html` html page. This action is defined because the button lives within a `<form>` tag and you have its `type='submit'`. You are setting those default values in the `<li>` when the page loads, so you are basically just reloading the page when that button is clicked. Read more about [forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, when you push the submit button you reload the Test1Verkoopwedstrijd2.html file. So don't use submit button in this case, or use a different event or return false to the event:

```js
function processForm(){
        var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
            var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
            l = unescape(temp[1]);
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = l;
        }
    processForm();

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="Test1Verkoopwedstrijd2.html" method="get"> 
  <input type="text" name="serialNumber" id="myInput"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return myFunction()"/>
</form>

<div id="data"></div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can use on the input text, which imedietly filters the result:

```js
function processForm(){
        var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
            var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
            l = unescape(temp[1]);
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = l;
        }
    processForm();

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="Test1Verkoopwedstrijd2.html" method="get"> 
  <input type="text" name="serialNumber" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div id="data"></div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in this case you can show a different page when the user press the submit button.

But later on, look the ajax request, because that's how these results work normally. With ajax you ask the server to give back the result, and you just show it (of cousre onkeyup event on the textbox).

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: What should I use instead. (Sorry I'm not that good at coding.)

Comment: Thanks golddragon007.

Comment: You don't need to submit, when you start typing in the field the list will change. Use the 'Run code snippet' to see in action. And look carefully the HTML code, because there's no even anymore on the button.

Comment: Really sorry if I'm rude but I don't know what you are trying to say with your edit. I just don't understand. As I already said I'm not that good.

Comment: Could you say which part?

Comment: The list gets edited immediately but the div item doesn't. When I click the button the page reloads. Than the div is edited but not the list. (Sorry that I reacted so late. I was looking at the problem.)

Comment: For that you need server side processing, usually with PHP, ASP.NET or JAVA. I don't know how you edit the div, probably server side, but after submit the server should return only the correct one. So you need to reimplement also the filtering on server side (reason: javascript can be turned off and then the user won't see the filtered results). Ahh now I see you have a different function for that... Olala... please learn these if you want to do it seriously: HTML, Javascript and a server side technology (PHP, ASP.NET or JAVA), for styling CSS.

Comment: @golddragon007 really thanks for your help. I can't do that because I know none of those languages but I want to learn php. Have yourself a nice day. Or afternoon if you live in Europe.

Comment: And for fix this here, in the `processForm()` function set the value of the myInput field (to the same as you set it for div) and then call the `myFunction()` after it. And the `myFunction()` should be first defined then the `processForm()`.